# Gradle Properties as gitlab environment variable

Tags: gradle, gitlab

Is there a way to pass all Gradle properties kept in the GitLab Enviroment variable,

let's say I will create a Variable ALL_IN_FOR_GRADLE with the following key=value pairs

```
A=V1
B=V2
```

using these key- values in

```
./gradlew e2e <PROPERTIES>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables) which is the standard way to configure gradle using environment variables. You can also expand variables within variables, so you could compose `GRADLE_OPTS` from other variables in your GitLab `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```yaml
variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: $ALL_IN_FOR_GRADLE
  # OR
  GRADLE_OPTS: "org.gradle.foo=bacon org.gradle.bar=eggs"
```

Alternatively, you can create a [file type variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-types) for the `gradle.properties` file... however this would likely conflict with repos which commit their own `gradle.properties` so I would not recommend that.